# What's wrong with Yahoo finance webservice v1? API changed?

Tags: web-services, curl

I was used to type in a browser : `http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/YHOO,AAPL/quote?bypass=true&format=json&view=detail` and parse the answer...

It's not working anymore, see: [Has Yahoo finance web service disappeared? API changed? Down temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355075/has-yahoo-finance-web-service-disappeared-api-changed-down-temporarily/38454315#38454315)

The command

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; MotoG3 Build/MPI24.107-55) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.81 Mobile Safari/537.36" http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/YHOO,AAPL/quote?bypass=true&format=json&view=detail
```

gives also

> not a valid parameter.

Any idea what's wrong in the request?

Any idea on the way to send the http request directly so it works in a desktop browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the headers below in your GET request, it will work...

```
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13E230 Safari/601.1"
```