# How can I get the stock price, volume from finance.yahoo.com?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am new to Java and I am trying to get the stock price , volume using JSOUP from finance.yahoo.com. 
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/aapl

The numbers are in the div, table tags. For instance for AAPL:
The Div is a class of "D(ib) W(1/2) ....." Then there is table ,class of W(100%) , then tbody, tr , td and and last is the span tag.

How can I get the value from the span tag,

Comment: Show what you've tried, there is multiple ex of Jsoup on this forum

Comment: By the way, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355075/has-yahoo-finance-web-service-disappeared-api-changed-down-temporarily

Comment: Jsoup can be a good alternative to a REST/JSON API especially as HTML should be just another representation of the same data as delivered via JSON (though a bit more verbose). IMHO your question is pretty valid, especially as the yahoo-finance webservice seemed to be shut down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to navigate from a unique point in the HTML structure to the data and try to rely only on "stable" information, i.e. the label for a field instead of the row count.

For instance let's take the Volume information. Analyze the HTML to get a uniquely identifiable element, i.e. the table with all the information. In this case it would be the `div id="quote-summary"`.

From there you you could get the table and it's rows (`tr`). Now iterate to the table row, that contains a `span` with the text "*Volume*".

Once you found that row, get either the 2nd `td` or the next `td` sibling of the one with the "Volume"-`span`. This `td` contains your span with the Volume value.

```
String fieldToFiend = "Volume";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/aapl").get();

//get the root element
Element quoteSummary = doc.getElementById("quote-summary");
String value = quoteSummary.getElementsByTag("tr")
                           //iterate over the table rows inside
                           .stream()
                           //find the row with the first td/span containing the label
                           .filter(tr -> fieldToFiend.equals(tr.getElementsByTag("span").first().text()))
                           //get the 2nd td and it's span element
                           .map(tr -> tr.getElementsByTag("td")
                                        .first()
                                        .nextElementSibling()
                                        .getElementsByTag("span")
                                        .first()
                                        .text())
                           //get the first match
                           .findFirst()
                           .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);

System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Thank you very much